# How to manage a big amount of relative data (categories, tags, menu) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 50 categories on my website. Some of them are parent.

Example:
News (id: 1, parent: 0)
- Tech (id: 3, parent: 1)
- World (id: 4, parent: 1)
Fun (id: 2, parent: 0)
- Movies (id: 5, parent: 2)
- ...
...

How can I properly manage it in Laravel? Probably I need to seed database, but what I need to do before seeding? How to correctly store this type of data. In future amount of categories can be increased or decreased. So I want to have an ability of syncing database and file with my categories and their relations.

Is there any advice for how to keep all this data with its relations and names before putting it into database and when necessary to update database with new values?

Comment: You would want two tables I believe, like main_categories and sub_categories. Main categories would have id,name, etc. and Sub categories would have id, main_category_id (foreign key), name etc.  You can build models for both of these tables and set the relationships between them.

Comment: It's only valid if you will have no more than one layer of parent -> child. If you want a parent -> child ->  ... -> child you better create one table like category_id, parent_category_id

Comment: I was in the same situation. I made use of only one table. I had these two columns: `category_name` and `parent_category_id`. If the category has no parent categories then you store a `0` inside the `parent_category_id` column. If the category has a parent category then you store the parent category's id in the 'parent_category_id' column. If you want all the parent categories, then you can just do a search where the 'parent_category_id' is equal to 0. This is for me the best way to do it. No other tables, no extra columns as well.

Comment: I already have DB Schema (id, name, parent_id, visibility). I need any recommendations for my file which will provide these categories to database and any ideas how to sync this file and database table.

Comment: @JuanJ forgot to mention you.